# How to successfully build NodeJS project with pug templating engine using webpack 4

Tags: node.js, webpack

This is going to be a little long and I was thinking I should maybe split it into two questions but I feel it all ties together and gives better context, so here goes...My build attempts have been failing for almost two days now and I can't seem to find any solutions. My project is basically a REST API with the index page accessible via `localhost:5000`. The project structure is as follows:

```
controllers
init
  - db.js
models
public
  - css
routes
views
  - layout.pug
  - index.pug
.babelrc
.env
app.js
start.js
package.json
webpack.server.config.js
webpack.prod.config.js
```

The entry point of the project is `start.js` which imports a function from the `db.js` file and a constant `app` from the `app.js` file. The `app.js` file imports and sets up express `const app = express()` adds all relevant middleware and exports the constant `app`. The `db.js` file in the `init` folder exports a function, (`export default function { ... }`), which initializes the database.
`app.js` and `db.js` come together inside `start.js` which looks like so...

```
import InitializeDB from "./init/db";
import app from "./app";

InitializeDB();
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);
const server = app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
  console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

And because I wanted to use ES6 imports, I installed babel `npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env @babel/node` and added this to `.babelrc`

```
{   
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env"   
  ] 
}
```

My `package.json` scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf dist && webpack --mode production --config webpack.server.config.js && webpack --mode production --config webpack.prod.config.js",
    "start": "node ./dist/server.bundle.js",
    "watch": "nodemon --exec babel-node start.js --ignore public/",
    "start:dev": "concurrently \"npm run test\" \"npm run watch\"",
    "test": "echo \"Testing...\""
  },
```

Locally, `npm run start:dev` gets everything running fine. However, that's where my success ends.

My first problem is that when I try to run `node ./start.js` I get hit with the error `(node:149228) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.`
So then I add `"type": "module"` in my `package.json` and run `npm run start:dev` again but then I get the Error...

```
internal/modules/run_main.js:54
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'G:\apps\myproject\init\db' imported from G:\apps\myproject\start.js
Did you mean to import ../init/db.js?
```

That's my first problem. Now for the webpack part...

My `webpack.server.config.js`...

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    server: "./start.js",
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    publicPath: "/",
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
  },
  target: "node",
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false,
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

My `webpack.prod.config.js` file...

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: "./start.js",
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    publicPath: "/",
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
  },
  target: "node",
  devtool: "source-map",
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        cache: true,
        parallel: true,
        sourceMap: true,
      }),
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({}),
    ],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        use: ["pug-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: ["file-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./views/index.pug",
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css",
    }),
  ],
};
```

For the `webpack.prod.config.js` file, some suggest changing `target` to `web` instead of `node` but that hasn't worked for me.

When I run `npm run build` with `"type": "module"` set in `package.json`, webpack throws the error

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: G:\apps\myproject\webpack.server.config.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of G:\apps\myproject\webpack.server.config.js from G:\apps\myproject\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename webpack.server.config.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from G:\apps\myproject\package.json.
```

So then I remove `"type": "module"` from `package.json` and run `npm run build` again and this time I get a bunch of...
`Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression`and
`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'G:\apps\myproject\node_modules\...`
for multiple packages.

These issues have been gnawing at me quite a bit. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please put your project into a public repo on Github and post the link? That way I can download it and play around with it to figure out the issue.

Comment: Here is the link to the repo https://github.com/keoak/node-webpack

Answer (score 1):

> That's my first problem. Now for the webpack part...

Your first problem needs to update your codebase as ESM requires:

- all your `*.js` files should be renamed to `*.mjs`. Adding `{type: 'module'}` in your `package.json` avoid this tedious operation since it will [enable/override](https://medium.com/@nodejs/announcing-core-node-js-support-for-ecmascript-modules-c5d6dc29b663) this check
- if you are using node>=8 <13 you must run your server with `node --experimental-modules start.js`
- ESM doesn't support `require, exports, module.exports, __filename, __dirname` so you need to change your `__dirname` to:

```
import { dirname } from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

...
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
...
```

- all the ESM relative import must have the extension, so you need to change all your imports to:

```
import Routes from './routes/index.js' // added .js
// etc.. for all the files
```

At the end, `node --experimental-modules start.js` will start:

[image: screen]

---

For the webpack part, instead, you need to:

```
npm i @open-wc/webpack-import-meta-loader -D
```

And add it to your `webpack.prod.config.js` file (I just remove `UglifyJsPlugin` since it wasn't working):

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  loader: require.resolve('@open-wc/webpack-import-meta-loader')
}
```

Comment: First part works great but the webpack part still does not build successfully. I commented out the uglifyJs stuff and replaced `'babel-loader'` with `require.resolve('@open-wc/webpack-import-meta-loader')` inside `webpack.prod.config.js` but I still get the error, `require() of ES modules is not supported.` from `webpack-cli` inside `node_modules`.

Comment: I forgot to write that I changed the `target: 'node',` too and build with `webpack --mode production --config webpack.prod.config.js`

Comment: I'm still getting the error. Am I supposed to also change all the require statements to `import` in the webpack config file? I've done that and replaced `modules.export = ` with `export default` but still no success.

Comment: No, I didn't change the `require` statement there

Comment: Still no success.